# Issue loading multiple instances of jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, jplayer

I have a script that is auto-generating the HTML necessary to create multiple instances of jplayer video players and instantiating them after creating. But with about 9 instances at once, the ajax handler seems to lock up and won't process any more ajax calls to anything, not even local html files after this. I've remediated the problem by creating a custom event handler that instantiates the jplayers, that is only called when those players are visible. But is there some inherent limitation to the number of jplayer instances that can be processed at once? Or is there a problem somewhere else?

I want to stress that the players are working with the lazy loading scheme now, and most were working before, but all subsequent ajax communication failed until I lazy loaded the $().jplayer() calls.

Comment: There's no inherent limit that I know of. Show us your code so we can help, or it's all just theory.

Answer (score 0):

it's nothing to do with jPlayer itself but the environment jPlayer executes in might have restrictions.. For example, Mobile Safari and Android will only permit one jPlayer instance at a time..